# Reduce the disadvantages of a Single Compilation Unit / Unity Builds

Tags: c++, performance, build

I'm working on a large project which is about to get much larger. One of the issues I'd like to tackle, before that happens, is build speed.

In the past we used Single Compilation Unit / Unity Builds to greatly improve the build speed. Details can be found here http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/

In essence you create one .cpp file with multiple #include other.cpp

e.g. Contents of scu.cpp

```
#include apple.cpp
#include banana.cpp
#include cherry.cpp
```

.....

which creates one scu.obj. This cuts down on build speed because it reduces file I/O.

But there are disadavantages

- Global variables/functions in the .cpp are shared and can conflict
- Developers can forget to #include files in the .cpp & get away with it

Another bad thing is that, potentially, developers would need to manually maintain scu.cpp (but this will be automation for us so its not a concern).

Because of these disadvantages we moved away from SCU. But I'm tempted to bring it back because the build speed improvement is **really** tempting (50 - 75% reduction).

Is there any way to avoid these conflicts? I tested

Contents of scu.cpp

```
namespace unique_1 {
#include apple.cpp
}
namespace unique_2 {
#include banana.cpp
}
namespace unique_3 {
#include cherry.cpp
}
```

but that just produces errors

```
error C3083: 'vc_attributes': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
........
```

which stem from #including within a namespace.

Is there an alternative? Are there any other solutions?

This thread suggestions no (unfortunately)

[Safe Unity Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136539/safe-unity-builds)

A separate build to test the non-SCU solution is easily doable. But frowned upon within our organisation. i.e.

- Global variables/functions are valid (in c++ text book)
- Could break SCU/non-SCU without realising (until build breakage occurs)

Comment: "Global variables ... can conflict" <- Imho, that should be tackled by looking at (a) how many of them actually should be global and (b) using namespaces as a conscious design decision throughout the project instead of wrapping them around files arbitrarily as an afterthought.

Comment: Compilation is an integer problem, file I/O plays no role in build speed on modern machines with a good file system cache and lots of RAM.  You get fast builds by modularizing your code into separate executables.

Comment: For large projects, it's **much** better to only rebuild small components whose code changed. When everything goes into one source file, a minor change means recompiling the entire project.

Comment: I like to use scripting for things like Unity builds. One company I worked for used a C# CLI app which read the source directory and would spit out a compatible project file and associated unity files. Nice, but a bit hacky; I prefer to use CMake, which comes with other benefits, but my favourite is the scripting language it uses, which allows you to create unity source files automatically. Give it a try, you might be surprised how well it works: http://cheind.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/reducing-compilation-time-unity-builds/

Comment: us2012 - I'm not a big fan of globals in .cpp. Seems very 80s. I'd argue for removing them. But it is valid c++ & its hard to argue that when people object. Agree namespaces should be a conscious choice. But I was hoping to find something to mitigate the disadvantages of SCU. Changing the entire code base to using namespaces is not practical for me.

Comment: Hans Passant - I'm not't claiming to be an expert. But with SCU I dropped a sub-components build time from 373 seconds to 274 seconds. And I only applied SCU to a subset of that code. If rolled out further I would expect to see greater gains. I tested this on a 2.8 GHz 8 core machine with 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Pete Becker - You are correct. I was intending to use SCU for full CI rebuilds or for the consumers of the code base. i.e. People who don't change the source but do build it. Without SCU an incremental build took 22 seconds. But with SCU this degraded to 32 seconds. Note: I'm creating a scu.cpp per directory. It would be possible to have just one scu.cpp for the entire code base. I have not evaluated this yet (would need to fix alot of conflicts I imagine).

Comment: fixxxer - I agree. We use scons. Its trivial to script SCU. Can even set a flag for it. e.g. scons SCU=TRUE. Heard good things about CMake but also heard it has its own weird scripting language (YAL). scons has the advantage of using Python. That said I've never used CMake so can't judge.